# 2014 Silverado 6 cyl extended cab 2 wheel drive oil dip stick

Tags: dipstick

I HATE this dipstick! I'm 50, should be carrying reader glasses around, but refuse to.....just yet! Anyway, that shouldn't matter. I should be able to check my oil by laying and rolling my dipstick on a clean rag to check the level. Idk why, but I cannot read my level! Does anyone else have this problem? Can someone please offer an equivalent dipstick that has holes in it to make it more obvious to read? Where can I get it?

Comment: What kind of rag are you using, along with the color, try using a piece of toilet paper or a paper towel, or you could always drill 2 tiny holes in your dipstick

Comment: Post a picture of your dipstick.  (Did I actually just type that out loud ??)

Comment: Yeah, they have been making working dipsticks forever, now all of a sudden GM forgot how.